# Tricky type signature for pairs of reversed pairs

Tags: haskell

Lets say I have the following data type:

```
data D a b = D (a,b) (b,a)
```

And I want to define the following function on it:

```
apply f (D x y) = D (f x) (f y)
```

What is the type signature of `apply`?

Here are some examples of `f` which are okay:

```
f :: a -> a -- OK
f :: (a, b) -> (b, a) -- OK
f :: (a, b) -> ((a, c), (b, c)) -- OK
```

In all of the above cases, we end up with a valid type D.

But this is not okay:

```
f :: (a, b) -> (a, a)
```

Because when we send such a function through `apply` we end up having to attempt to construct `D (a,a) (b,b)` which is not valid unless `a = b`.

I can't seem to work out a type signature to express all this? Also, in general, is there a way to get GHC to tell me what these signatures should be?

**Typed Holes Edit:**

In an attempt to find the type using typed holes, I tried the following:

```
x = apply _ (D (1::Int,'a') ('b',2::Int))
```

And got:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: (Int, Int) -> (b, b)
Where: ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of x :: D b b
```

Which seems to me to be nonsense as `f :: (Int, Int) -> (b, b)` is clearly not going to work here.

Comment: "is there a way to get GHC to tell me what these signatures should be?" - Have you looked at [typed holes](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes)?

Comment: I just did, and got what seems to be nonsense back, as detailed in the edit.

Comment: According to `ghci`, `apply :: ((t, t) -> (b, b)) -> D t t -> D b b`.

Comment: That seems to be what `ghc` infers but surely `apply` can have a more general type because `apply id x` should be valid.

Comment: @Clinton `id :: x -> x` does match `(t,t) -> (b,b)`, with `t=b` and `x=(t,t)`.

Comment: My point is that 'apply id x' should be valid for x :: D a b not just D a a.

Comment: @Clinton Ah, here's the problem then.  You want existentials.  Think of it this way, when you have `apply id`, the compiler sees `id` specialized to only one type in context, not the more general form as defined elsewhere.  There are all sorts of technical reasons for doing it this way that don't fit well into a SO comment, but be assured that they are good reasons.

Comment: @bheklilr: you mean universals (at higher rank)?

Comment: @AndrásKovács Quite possibly, but I thought this could be achieved in a limited sense using `ExistentialQuantification`?

Comment: Can I write the type signature as a rank-n type then? If so how?

Comment: I think you need [intersection types](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/papers/thesis.pdf) to properly typify this function. Something like `apply :: ((a, b) -> (c, d)) & ((b, a) -> (d, c)) -> D a b -> D c d`.

Comment: @user3237465 You can "deal" with type-level abstractions and their equivalence proofs. `apply :: forall t. ((a, b) ~ t (c, d), (b, a) ~ t (d, c)) => ((c, d) -> (a, b)) -> D c d -> D a b`

Comment: @mniip I don't see, how equivalence proofs can help in this case. `(a, b) -> (c, d)` and `(b, a) -> (d, c)` are really two different types. Could you elaborate? I can't make your `apply` typecheck, when the body of the function is provided.

Answer (score 8):

Multiple types fit `apply`, but the inferred `((t, t) -> (b, b)) -> D t t -> D b b` is the most sensible and usable one. The alternatives are going to be higher-rank, so let's enable that language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

First, we can make `apply id` work:

```
apply :: (forall a. a -> a) -> D a b -> D a b
apply f (D x y) = D (f x) (f y)
```

However, now `id` is the *only* function with which `apply` works (all total functions of type `forall a. a -> a` are equal to `id`).

Here's another type:

```
apply :: (forall a. a -> (c, c)) -> D a b -> D c c
apply f (D x y) = D (f x) (f y)
```

But this too comes at a price. Now the `f`-s can only be constant functions that ignore the previous fields of `D`. So `apply (const (0, 0))` works, but we have no way to inspect the argument of `f`.

In contrast, the inferred type is pretty useful. We can express transformations with it that look at the actual data contained in `D`.

At this point, we might ask: why does GHC infer what it infers? After all, some functions work with the alternative types, but don't work with the default type. Could it be better to sometimes infer higher-ranked types? Well, such types are often extremely useful, but inferring them is unfeasible.

Type inference for rank-2 types is rather complicated, and not very practical either, because it's not possible to infer *most general* types. With rank-1 inference, we can infer a type that is more general than all other valid types for the same expression. There's no such guarantee with rank-2 types. And inference for rank-3 and above types is just [*undecidable*](http://www.cs.bu.edu/pub/jbw/types/finite-rank.ps).

For these reasons, GHC sticks to rank-1 inference, so it never infers types with `forall`-s inside function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Taking things to extremes of generality, we want a type that looks like

```
apply :: tf -> D a b -> D c d
```

where `tf` represents the type of `f`. In order to apply `f` to `(a,b)` and get `(c,d)`, we need

```
tf ~ (a,b) -> (c,d)
```

In order to apply `f` to `(b,a)` to get `(d,c)`, we need

```
tf ~ (b,a) -> (d,c)
```

If we turn on `TypeFamilies` (or `GADTs`) we get the magic constraint we need to express that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

apply :: (((a,b) -> (c,d)) ~ tf,
          ((b,a) -> (d,c)) ~ tf) =>
         tf -> D a b -> D c d
```

I suspect this is one of the most general types available. Unfortunately, it's pretty wild; working through whether a particular application will pass the type checker is not always so easy. Note also that for reasons I don't personally understand, you can't reliably define specializations using

```
apply' :: ...
apply' = apply
```

Instead, you sometimes must use

```
apply' f = apply f
```